# 'You're a creepy psycho' message in GTAV?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Whilst driving around and mowing a few people down (playing as Trevor) in the Sandy Shores area, near a big grain/corn silo factory (several big tanks etc. I think), the words 'You're a creepy psycho' appeared on the screen as the usual subtitles/CC text (which in itself is weird as I don't have subtitles turns on).

I was being chased by the cops and got shot before I could investigate further but does anyone know what this was? Is it part of a random event that I missed? I haven't been able to come across this again since. A bit of Googling shows a few forum posts relating to this but no answers/follow ups.

Comment: It was probably a glitch, this is a line that pedestrians may say whenever you're doing something particularly nasty.

Comment: I think there's more to it than that. There were people standing outside a car when this happened - possibly talking to each other which makes me think it is something to do with a random event.

Comment: @IvoCoumans You could offer that as an answer. There's sure to be an archive of game scripted lines that you could reference.

Comment: I've been trying to research it and find stuff like that, but no luck so far. I'd like to answer, but not until I've found some proof!

Answer (score 4):

Rockstar has a tendency to give NPCs very random quotes that you wouldn't expect them to have included, just to add a bit of humour in some cases, and in some to give a realistic response to what's going on.

Most notably, I've had moments where I'll drive past some people with a prostitute in my car (dat health regen) and I'll hear something along the lines of "You're a creep!" or "Pervert!"

I think this is being read into a little much, as if it were truly something you would have found a concrete answer somewhere on google, given how long it's already been out.

Comment: Fair point... :)